# How to add html inside {{ }} in django template

Tags: python, html, django, model

I want to know how to add html inside {{  }}:

```
{{ article.tags.all|join:", "  }}
```

This return tags separated by coma for example: sports, cricket, nature etc

I want to do this:

```
{{ <span class="label">article.tags.all|join:", "</span>  }}
```

I want to design each tag with adding a span class and remove coma

**Models.py:**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default='')

class article(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   disc = models.TextField(verbose_name="Discription")
   posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
{% for tag in article.tags.all %}
  <span class="label">{{ tag }}</span>{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

*After following the discussion:*

```
{% for tag in article.tags.all %}
  {% if tag.title == 'hello' %}
    Special tag: <span>{{ tag }}</span>
  {% else %}
    <span>{{ tag }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It works thanks for quick response and also help me how to use if statement inside this {% if {{ some variable }} == '' % } ?

Comment: please also tell me how to use if statement like this:
 **{% if {{ some variable }} == '' % } **

Comment: your variable is from the backend or javascript variable?

Comment: what your example variable?

Comment: My variable is from database. I want to adding some conditions on them in html template.
for example: ** {% if {{ post }} %} some text {% endif %}**

Comment: inside `{% for tag`?, yes you can.. eg: `{% if post == '' %}hello{% endif %}`

Comment: I want to do this: {% if {{ tag }} %} <b>Tag</b>{% endif %}
but it gives me error